# Gitlab CI/CD - saving test coverage % in a regex variable?

Tags: bash, gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, devops

Recently I added test coverage to our CI/CD pipeline, so we have the % of coverage outputted after each job. Currently our `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
run tests:
  stage: test
  image: python:3
  script:
    - pip install pytest pytest-cov
    - coverage run -m pytest
    - coverage report
    - coverage xml
  coverage: '/TOTAL.*\s([.\d]+)%/'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage.xml
```

Coverage is a gitlab CI keyword and it pulls the total % coverage from coverage report using regex on the total coverage that is outputted to the terminal. I want to save the coverage to a variable so I can compare it to a threshold number and fail the pipeline if it goes below the threshold. I tried:

```
  variables:
    coverage_percent: '/TOTAL.*\s([.\d]+)%/'
  after_script:
    - echo $coverage_percent
```

But `$coverage_percent` just gets saved as exact string `'/TOTAL.*\s([.\d]+)%/'` - it doesn't perform a regex on the terminal like the coverage command does. How can I either a) save the result of coverage: `'/TOTAL.*\s([.\d]+)%/'` or b) perform regex with a variable in the pipeline?

Comment: try changing the single quotes to double quotes:  `"/TOTAL.*\s([.\d]+)%/"`

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the gitlab api to pull the value out and perform a comparison, then based on the result of that fail your pipeline.

https://www.reddit.com/r/gitlab/comments/agqhnt/using_gitlab_api_to_access_code_coverage/ has an example of how to do this.

[image]

Depending on how often the pipelines value (the bit after /pipelines/) in the URL changes this might work for you :)